# GMP - division precision or printing issue

Tags: c++, gmp

I need to display first 100 meaning digits of result of average computation of integers. Serie of integers is stored in array of mpz_t type, then it's summed to mpq_t and divided by another mpq_t (count)

Code:

```
mpq_t sum;
mpq_init(sum);
//same for variable count, they are filled from mpz_t

//display for check
gmp_printf("%.Qd\n", sum); <- here everything correct
gmp_printf("%.Qd\n", count); <- here also

mpq_div(sum, sum, count);

//to display with floating point
mpf_t avg;
mpf_init(avg);
mpf_set_q(avg, sum);

gmp_printf("%.100Ff\n", avg);
```

The display in last line, let's say for sum = 2, count = 3 is wrong. It is ceiled after about 10-15 digits and filled with 0. For (2/3) it's 0.66666666670000...

So two things:

1. I don't want to floor/ceil it, simply truncate after 100 digits
2. fill all 100 digits with meaning digits

So for (2/3) desired output is:

0.666...666 (hundred of 6, also with 6 at the end)

Answer (score 5):

Use mpf_init2(avg, prec), where prec is the desired minimum precision in bits. Note that behind the scenes, GMP works in groups of (usually) either 32 or 64 bits and so the actual precision for a calculation is at least your requested precision.

Preventing rounding on the output will be more difficult. I would recommend using the MPFR library. It is a much more complete floating point library and is designed to replace GMP's mpf type.

Too long for a comment.....

Calculating to more than 100 digits just requires changes mpf_int(x) to mpf_init2(x, 333). 333 bits should get at least 100 decimal digits of precision but you may want to increase it slightly.

Getting truncated output will be trickier since gmp_printf() may round the last digit up. An approach that will "almost always" work is to use mpf_get_str() to create a string with more than 100 digits of precision and then truncating the string.

The "almost always" is because a long sequence of nines, say ...599999999 will be rounded to ...600000000 and the truncated string might include the 6. Increasing the precision of your mpf calculations will decrease the odds of encountering this problem.

MPFR has mpfr_printf() which allows you control the rounding of the formatted output. For example, mpfr_printf("%.100RZf, avg) will print avg with 100 digits of precision and round toward zero.

Comment: any chance of achieving it with gmp?